# Perform aggregation/analytical operations on Dimensions SQL

Tags: sql, subquery

How to perform analytical query over dimensions? I tried to do it but i'm not convinced by the query that i've written. I'm looking for more generic and logical approach to this problem. Also for some tips to look for while performing aggregations on dimensional fields.

my query:

```sql
select x.id, total areas, location as max_area from
(select id, count(id) as total areas from test_set group by id) x
inner join (
select *, rank() over (partition by id order by count desc) as rnk from(
select id, location, count (id) as count from test_set group by id, location)x) y on x.id = y.id where rnk= 1
```

schema:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_SET (ID VARCHAR2(5), LOCATION VARCHAR2(10))

INSERT INTO TEST_SET(ID,LOCATION) VALUES('L2','BANGALORE')
INSERT INTO TEST_SET(ID,LOCATION) VALUES('L2','BANGALORE')
INSERT INTO TEST_SET(ID,LOCATION) VALUES('L2','BANGALORE')
INSERT INTO TEST_SET(ID,LOCATION) VALUES('L2','BANGALORE')
INSERT INTO TEST_SET(ID,LOCATION) VALUES('L2','DELHI')
INSERT INTO TEST_SET(ID,LOCATION) VALUES('L2','DELHI')
INSERT INTO TEST_SET(ID,LOCATION) VALUES('L3','MUMBAI')
INSERT INTO TEST_SET(ID,LOCATION) VALUES('L3','MUMBAI')
INSERT INTO TEST_SET(ID,LOCATION) VALUES('L3','HONGKONG')
INSERT INTO TEST_SET(ID,LOCATION) VALUES('L3','HONGKONG')
INSERT INTO TEST_SET(ID,LOCATION) VALUES('L3','HONGKONG')
```

INPUT: TEST_SET

| ID | LOCATION |
| --- | --- |
| L2 | BANGALORE |
| L2 | BANGALORE |
| L2 | BANGALORE |
| L2 | BANGALORE |
| L2 | DELHI |
| L2 | DELHI |
| L3 | HONGKONG |
| L3 | HONGKONG |
| L3 | HONGKONG |
| L3 | MUMBAI |
| L3 | MUMBAI |

OUTPUT

| ID | TOTAL_AREAS | MAX_AREA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L2 | 6 | BANGALORE |
| L3 | 5 | HONGKONG |

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Oracle? If the former then the above will fail, `VARCHAR2` is not a valid data type in SQL Server.

Comment: I have used oracle above, but i don't mind much about the platform. Happy to see a sql server or oracle code written down here

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `CTE` or subquery get count each `ID`, `LOCATION`, then use `ROW_NUMBER` window function get `Max` count by `id`

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ID,
       LOCATION,
       COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM TEST_SET
  GROUP BY ID,
       LOCATION
)
SELECT t1.*,t2.LOCATION
FROM (
  SELECT ID,SUM(cnt) cnt
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY ID
) t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY id ORDER BY cnt desc) rn
  FROM CTE 
) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.rn = 1
```

otherwise, there is another simpler way to make it use a subquery.

```
SELECT ID,
       COUNT(*) cnt,
       (SELECT LOCATION 
       FROM TEST_SET tt WHERE t1.ID = tt.ID 
       GROUP BY LOCATION 
       ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
       LIMIT 1) MAX_AREA
  FROM TEST_SET t1
  GROUP BY ID
```

this [sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=45d8b8f9a11e3d234b3e7550748c4d40) made on sql-server

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  ranked_aggregate AS
(
  SELECT
    id,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY id) total_areas,
    location,
    COUNT(*)   location_count,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)  id_location_rank
  FROM
    test_set
  GROUP BY
    id,
    location
)
SELECT
  id,
  total_areas,
  location,
  location_count
FROM
  ranked_aggregate
WHERE
  id_location_rank = 1
```

Demo (borrowed from @D-Shih)

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0953f746871b454f1e3c4afec420438d